# Real Schur decomposition of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, orthogonal-matrices, schur-decomposition

The real Schur decomposition theorem states that for any matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and a "quasitriangular" matrix $T$ such that $A=QTQ^T$. Here, "quasitriangular" means that $T$ has the form

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}B_1&&&*\\&B_2&&\\&&\ddots&\\0&&&B_n\end{pmatrix},$$
where all $B_i$ are either $1\times1$ or $2\times2$ matrices. These matrices form the "quasidiagonal".

I want to prove that in the specific case of real Schur decomposition of an orthogonal matrix, $T$ must be a "quasidiagonal matrix", i.e. all entries above the quasidiagonal are zero. This is claimed without proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/433585/718671).

It's easy to see that $T$ must be orthogonal. In the special case where $T$ is upper triangular, it's simple to prove that the norm of the $i$-th column equals that of the $i$-th row, which then yields the desired result by a simple induction. However, my attempt at adapting this proof to the quasidiagonal case failed.

This result seems to me like it should be well-known. A reference would also suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A, T, Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $A=Q T Q^T$, $A$ and $Q$ are orthogonal. Then $T$ is orthogonal. We want to prove that if $T$ is quasitriangular, then it's quasidiagonal. This follows from the following theorem.

#### Theorem

Suppose
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1} & B_{1,2} & \dots  & B_{1,m} \\
        & B_{2,2} & \dots  & \vdots  \\
    &         & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    &     &        & B_{m,m}
\end{bmatrix}$$
is a real orthogonal or complex unitary block matrix, where each $B_{i,i}$ is a $1 \times 1$ or a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Then for each $i$ for each $j>i$ we have $B_{i,j}=0$.

#### Proof of the theorem

Since T is orthogonal or unitary, we have $T^* T = I$, which can be visualized as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1}^* &           &        &           \\
B_{1,2}^* & B_{2,2}^* &        &           \\
\vdots    & \vdots     & \ddots &           \\
B_{1,m}^* & \dots     & \dots  & B_{m,m}^*
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1} & B_{1,2} & \dots  & B_{1,m} \\
        & B_{2,2} & \dots  & \vdots  \\
    &         & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    &     &        & B_{m,m}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
I&&& \\
&I&& \\
&&\ddots& \\
&&&I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now we will prove by induction on $i$ that for each $i$, $B_{i,i}^*$ is invertible and for each $j > i$ we have $B_{i,j}=0$.

Base of induction: it can be seen from the structure of matrices in the equation above that $B_{1,1}^* B_{1,1} = I$ and thus $B_{1,1}^*$ is invertible, and that for each $j>1$, $B_{1,1}^* B_{1,j}=0$, which by invertibility of $B_{1,1}^*$ gives us $B_{1,j}=0$.

Inductive step. Suppose for each $i$ up to and including $k$, for each $j > i$ we have $B_{i,j}=0$. So, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1}^*&&&&&& \\
& \ddots &&&&& \\
&& B_{k,k}^* &&&& \\
&&&B_{k+1,k+1}^* &           &        &           \\
&&&B_{k+1,k+2}^* & B_{k+2,2}^* &        &           \\
&&&\vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots &           \\
&&&B_{k+1,m}^* & \dots     & \dots  & B_{m,m}^*
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1}&&&&&& \\
& \ddots &&&&& \\
&& B_{k,k} &&&& \\
&&&B_{k+1,k+1} & B_{k+1,k+2} & \dots  & B_{k+1,m} \\
        &&&& B_{k+2,k+2} & \dots  & \vdots  \\
    &&&&         & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    &&&&     &        & B_{m,m}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
I&&&&&& \\
&\ddots&&&&& \\
&&I&&&& \\
&&&I&&& \\
&&&&I&& \\
&&&&&\ddots& \\
&&&&&&I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
From the structure of matrices in this equation we can see that $B_{k+1,k+1}^* B_{k+1,k+1} = I$, which means that $B_{k+1,k+1}^*$ is invertible, and that for each $j > k+1$ we have $B_{k+1,k+1}^* B_{k+1,j} = 0$, which by invertibility of $B_{k+1,k+1}^*$ gives us $B_{k+1,j}=0$. QED

Comment: I don't quite see why $B_{ii}^*B_{ii}=I$. Doesn't the corresponding entry in the product have extra terms?

Comment: Wait, I understand now - this is actually part of what you prove during the induction. Many thanks!

Comment: @ViHdzP Oops, indeed, I should've included that in the induction. It can't be shown straightforwadly as I wrote it.

Comment: I have now fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the fact that $B_i$ are also orthogonal? For proving this, using $T^tT=TT^t=I$ on the diagonal (using block matrix).

Then you can easily prove that $*$ can only be zero, using $T^tT=TT^t=I$ besides diagonal step by step, from top row to bottom row.

Comment: Is this something we can prove, or a part of the definition I missed?

Comment: @ViHdzP I think using block matrix can reduce the case into upper triangular ones.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on background knowledge, but the simplest algebraic proof comes from knowing that

(i) Invertible Block upper triangular matrices (with specified dimensions for each diagonal block) form a group.
(ii) Inverses of orthogonal matrices are given by their transpose.

$T=Q^TAQ$
and $Q,A \in O_n\big(\mathbb R\big)\implies T \in O_n\big(\mathbb R\big)$
applying (i) we know $T^{-1}$ is block upper triangular and applying (ii) we know that $T^{-1}=T^T$ which must be block lower triangular since the transpose of a block upper triangular matrix is block lower triangular.

Thus $T^T$ is both block upper triangular and block lower triangular, i.e. $T^T$ is block diagonal, and so is $T$.

This sort of argument runs identically when you encounter an uglier group, like $Q,A \in O_n\big(\mathbb C\big)$
(the complex orthogonal group which is *not* the unitary group).

Comment: to clarify on (i), i.e. ref e.g. ex 2.4.12 of Artin's *Algebra* 1st edition where you show $\begin{pmatrix}A &* \\ \mathbf 0&D\end{pmatrix}$ for $A \in GL_r(\mathbb R)$ and $D\in \mathbb GL_{n-r}(\mathbb R)$ forms a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$-- once this is known, (i) follows almost immediately by strong induction.