# How to block diagonalize a orthogonal matrix?

Tags: rotations, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, block-matrices

I am trying to block diagonalize a real orthogonal matrix, A. The condition is that the blocks should also be orthogonal. I found this pretty old yet [abstract paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379576900264) that says
"By block diagonalization methods one can obtain eigenvalues and eigenvectors while simultaneously “reducing” the size of the matrix, i.e., $\sigma(A) = \sigma(\Lambda_1) \cup \sigma(\Lambda_2) $"

However, I am not a math major and can not understand much of it. So I am asking here if it is possible or implemented somewhere to block diagonalize a matrix. The matrices that I want to block diagonalize are always real, square, and orthogonal (satisfying $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A = 1$).

As a sample matrix, $ A = \begin{bmatrix} -0.874030050 & 0.634268244 & 0.001600016 & 0.000706214 \\\ 
0.917305750 & 0.569888842 & 0.000391318 & -0.001513837 \\\
0.001600016 & 0.000706214 & -0.874030050 &  0.634268244 \\\
0.000391318 & -0.001513837 & 0.917305750 & 0.569888842\end{bmatrix}$

Say, I want two 2x2 blocks, along the main diagonal. How to obtain this?

***EDIT1***
Is it possible to obtain a matrix like this?

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -0.874030050\pm c1  & 0.634268244\pm c2 & 0.0000001 & 0.00000004 \\\ 
0.917305750\pm c3 & 0.569888842\pm c4 & 0.00000008 & -0.00000037 \\\
0.000000016 & 0.000000014 & -0.874030050\pm c5 &  0.634268244\pm c6 \\\
0.000000018 & -0.00000037 & 0.917305750\pm c7 & 0.569888842\pm c8\end{bmatrix}$
What it means is that the $c_i$ are some corrections to the desired matrix blocks and the rest are zero or negligible. The Jordan Normal form is an upper triangular matrix and this is not what I want.

I think it can be made possible with the paper that I am [refering](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379576900264), but it is pretty old and I need an interpretation too, it contains a lot of terms that I do not know. Probably there are updated methods as well.

***EDIT 2***
I have read from [here](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Givens-rotation) that **Givens Rotation** can be applied to obtain orthonormal submatrices. I have applied multiple Givens Rotation to the matrix provided above. I am providing the result below. However, the desired result has not yet been obtained.
$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -0.909289121 & 0.598620192 & -0.001459999 & -0.0000000 \\\ 
0.909289121 &  0.598620192 & 0.001459999 & -0.00000000 \\\
-0.00000000 & -0.000959999 & 0.909290293 & 0.598619423 \\\
-0.00000000 & -0.000959999 & -0.909290293 & 0.598619423\end{bmatrix}$

I have used only two rotations and got the above result. Performing more rotations causes more harm. Is there any modified algorithm to this?

Comment: For general matrices, the block diagonalisation of a matrix can be described by the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). See also the section "Invariant subspace decompositions" therein.

Comment: For the numerics, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312216/compute-jordan-normal-form-of-matrix-in-python-numpy) post can help.

Comment: I was looking at the Jordan Normal form, which is not exactly what I want. However, I tried to implement that, and I think there might be some problem with the example provided with sympy as it runs for hours and does not output anything. However, I didn't know much about Jordan Normal form and thank you for your help. Could you please have a look at the edit and let me know what you think?

Comment: I see, yes, it makes sense!

Comment: Generally, there always are subspaces that decompose the matrix if it has *more than one* eigenvalue: Consider a disjoint decomposition of the spectrum $\sigma(A) = \sigma_1 \dot\cup \sigma_2$. Then there are subspaces $V_1\oplus V_2 = V$ such that $A$ maps $V_j$ into $V_j$, and the restriction of $A$ on $V_j$ satisfies $\sigma(A|_{V_j}) = \sigma_j$. The $V_j$ would be the (generalized) eigenspaces, and it should be possible to extract this from the Jordan normal form (the columns of the transformation matrix). But I have to admit I'm out of my depth here, maybe someone else knows more.

Comment: you wrote *"I am trying to block diagonalize a real orthogonal matrix, A. The condition is that the blocks should also be orthogonal"*. What does the second sentence mean?  They should be orthogonal matrices or orthogonal to each other?  In general Jordan Forms are not going to be helpful.  I suspect the Real Schur Decomposition will be though -- ref e.g. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320723/real-schur-decomposition-of-orthogonal-matrix

Comment: The equality $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A = 1$ holds for any non-singular matrix. A matrix $A$ is *orthogonal*, if $A^TA=1$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, you are right. That was my mistake.

Comment: @user8675309 I wanted to say that each will be an orthogonal matrix.
" They should be orthogonal matrices". Yes.
"orthogonal to each other". No

Answer (score 0):

As I understood Exercises to Chapter 4 of [Bel], we can proceed as follows. Let $N\ge 2$ be a natural number, $A$ be a $N\times N$ orthogonal matrix, and $\lambda\ne\pm 1$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ such that $|\lambda|=1$. Let the corresponding eigenvector is $x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real. Then the vectors $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. Now let
$T_1=(x,y,x^3,x^4,\dots,x^N)$ be an orthogonal matrix whose two columns are $x$ and $y$. Then
$$T_1^TAT_1=\begin{Vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\varphi_1 & - \sin\varphi_1 \\
\sin\varphi_1 & \cos\varphi_1
\end{pmatrix} & 0\\
0 & A_{N-2}\end{Vmatrix},
$$
where the matrix $A_{N-2}$ is orthogonal too. Proceeding by induction, we can build an orthogonal matrix $T$ such that $T^TAT$ is a block-diagonal matrix whose blocks are $\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\varphi_k & - \sin\varphi_k \\
\sin\varphi_k & \cos\varphi_k
\end{pmatrix}$ or $(\pm 1)$.

*References*

[Bel] Richard Bellman, *Introduction to matrix analysis*, McGraw-Hill book company, Inc., New York-Toronto-London, 1960, Russian translation, Nauka, Moscow, 1969.